# Traversing the DOM Tree jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

A fairly simple traversal that I can't seem to figure out...

Basically if someone clicks on the `<li>` and I want to change the image in the first div, how would I go about doing that? tried a few things including :

`$(this).closest('.currentImage img')`

```
<div class="imageSlider">
    <div class="currentImage">
        <img src="LP5/lp5_1.png"/>
    </div>
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li><img src="LP5/lp5_1.png"/></li>
        <li><img src="LP5/lp5_2.png"/></li>
        <li><img src="LP5/lp5_3.png"/></li>
        <li><img src="LP5/lp5_4.png"/></li>
        <li><img src="LP5/lp5_5.png"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('.thumbnails li').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var newImage = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
    var $image = $(this).closest('.currentImage img');
    $image.fadeOut(500, function() {
        $image.attr('src', newImage);
    }).fadeIn(500);
 });
```

Comment: $(this).parent().prev().children('img') or simple refer in a variable the wrapper (image-slider) so you can used it as a root selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L85Zs/1/)</kbd>

Try finding the parent `.imageSlider` element, and then finding its child `.currentImage` element.

```
$('.thumbnails li').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var newImage = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
    var $image = $(this).parents('.imageSlider').find('.currentImage img');
    console.log(newImage);
    $image.fadeOut(500, function() {
        $image.attr('src', newImage);
    }).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Another option would be `$(this).parent('ul').siblings('.currentImage').find('img')`.

Comment: Yeah, simple. ;) So how come when I did `$(this).parent('.imageSlider.currentImage img')` it didn't work?

Comment: First, you need a space in between `.imageSlider` and `.currentImage`. No space means they are the same element, i.e. an element with both classes. Second, `$(this).parent(selector)` finds the immediate parent of the `$(this)` element, but only returns it if it matches the selector. The immediate parent of `$(this)` is a `<ul>` element. Third, `$(this).parents(selector)` starts with the immediate parent, then gets the parent of that, and recurses like that until it finds an element that matches the selector, which will never happen because `.currentImage` is not a parent of the `<li>` element.

Comment: Yes, sorry...went home for the night and forgot to accept because of the 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

That selector isn't exactly right. `.currentImage` is a sibling of the current element's parent (ie `.thumbnails`), so `closest()` will never find it.